# How to use AsyncSession from sqlalchemy in celery tasks?

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, celery, fastapi

Use AsyncSession in celery tasks

I use fastapi and sqlalchemy, I must create celery task, that will go to the database and check does any objects of my Event (table) has end_time < datetime.now()

There is my code:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def scoped_session():
    scoped_factory = async_scoped_session(
        async_session,
        scopefunc=asyncio.current_task()
    )
    try:
        async with scoped_factory() as s:
            yield s
    finally:
        await scoped_factory().remove()


async def logic():
    async with scoped_session() as session:
        stmt = select(event.models.Event).where(
            event.models.Event.end_time <= datetime.now()
        )
        results = await session.execute(stmt)
        for res in results.fetchall():
            print(res.is_event_done)


@celery.task(name='is_event_done', bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def is_event_done(self):
    asyncio.run(logic())
```

here is my async_session

```
engine = create_async_engine(settings.db_url, echo=True)

async_session = sessionmaker(
    engine,
    class_=AsyncSession,
    expire_on_commit=False
)
```

so I got `\'_asyncio.Task\' object is not callable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just do like this

```
async def update_event() -> None:
    async with async_session() as session:
        stmt = update(event.models.Event).where(
            event.models.Event.end_time <= datetime.now(),
            event.models.Event.is_active is True
        ).values(is_done=True)
        await session.execute(stmt)


@celery.task(name='is_event_done', bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def is_event_done(self) -> None:
    loop.run_until_complete(update_event())
```

and now its work fine, I hope that its a good solution
If there is anything wrong let me know, thanks!